# Circle overlay follow user location

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, location, overlay

How can i make my custom circle overlay follow as a subview the current user location in real time? I have managed to display my circle overlay and get to the center of userlocation but when user moves (gps) the overlay stays still and does not followuser. How do i fix that? Thank you in advance..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02))];
[self configureOverlay];

[[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

in configureOverlay:

```
        CircleOverlay *overlay = [[CircleOverlay alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:self.radius];

    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlay];

    GeoQueryAnnotation *annotation = [[GeoQueryAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:self.radius];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

I also tried using:

```
 CLLocation *location = _locationManager.location;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
```

and replacing coordinate with self.location.coordinate

any advise would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Tell your class you are going to implement CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
@interface YourClass () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Then add the following methods:

```
    #pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
//You can change the overlay coordinates here. Even with an animation if you want.

    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorType = (error.code == kCLErrorDenied) ? @"Access Denied" : @"Unknown Error";
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error getting Location"message:errorType delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

The locationManager:didUpdateToLocation... method will be triggered each time the location manager detects a change in the user's position.

Cheers.

**EDIT**
I forgot about something very important. In your viewDidLoad method add your class as the delegate:

```
self.locationmanager.delegate = self;
```

Comment: ok.. although this works and thank you.. it seems like its flashing all the time (updates location). Is there a way to make it more efficient and not looking like its flashing?

Comment: @snksnk You could try two things: First, check if the location is the same than before, and in that case don't update it. Also, you could try to use animations to perform the coordinates' change, using http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:   If my answer works, pleace accept it. I encourage you to ask another question regarding your problems with animations. Place the code you are using to update the view there, and let people help you :) cheers.